# jFugue incorrectly parsing tempo

Tags: parsing, midi, jfugue

I'm using jFugue to parse a midi file and it will always parse the tempo incorrectly(I know that the tempo is 140 and it is saying that the tempo is 720). At first I thought that it might, somehow, be multiplying the actual tempo by some number and that's not it. The number it's giving me is somehow related to the tempo, but I don't know how. This whole thing is very confusing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes for really slow tempos, under around 50, it will give me negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here it says that if you're using a version of JFugue before 4.0, tempo is stored as microseconds per beat, which is 60000 / BPM 
http://www.jfugue.org/javadoc/org/jfugue/Tempo.html

**Correction:**
The conversion information on that page is incorrect.
PPQ (pulses per quarter, or microseconds per beat) = 60,000,000 / BPM

Comment: I have the latest stable version of JFugue, 4.0.3. So I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I tried myself, and had the same issue as you. JFugue seems to have some issues parsing Tempo from Midi. If you do: Player player = new Player(); Pattern pattern = player.loadMidi(new File("song.mid")); player.play(pattern); player.close();   -- it seems to inevitably play the song too slowly.